# How to grep from file names with number in range

Tags: command-line, grep, macos, json

Assume I have a directory with 5,000 files. each with a name such as:

```
1.json
2.json
3.json
..
4000.json
4001.json
```

what command-line utility can I use to grep for a string from only the files 1.json through 2000.json?

Comment: Are you looking for a specific _key_ or _value_ in one of those JSON files? What are you wanting to do with the files that match? I'm just asking because it's usually safer to use a JSON parser such as `jq` to process JSON data. The `grep` utility can't decode encoded strings, it doesn't undrestand the structure of JSON files, and it can't tell a key from a value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash, Ksh, Zsh:

```
grep pattern {1..2000}.json
```

Were the file names zero-padded:

```
grep pattern {0001..2000}.json
```